# Policy on answering old questions

Tags: discussion

Is there a standard policy on answering old questions?  What about questions that have already had accepted answers?

I don't want to flood the top of the queue with old questions simply because I supplied an answer.  I guess a follow-on comment would be that it would be nice if either

1. Questions older than such-and-such a date didn't jump to the top, or
2. There was a checkbox for old questions that said, "do not move question to the top."

Comment: This really runs counter to the goal of the site. An accepted answer could be replaced by an even better one—but if the old question doesn't resurface, no one will know it's there! (Hence my downvote.)

Comment: Okay, if it is okay to answer old questions, then that's great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I don't see anything wrong with the fact that new answers to old questions come to the top, on the contrary. I certainly would like to see new answers, and be able to up/down-vote them.

If you want to avoid flooding the front page with old questions, then perhaps don't submit too many answers at once :)

Comment: I suppose you're right--being able to up/down vote them would be nice.  It is a bit jarring to see a new answer pop up to an old question sometimes.